# Scraping tabulated paginated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-scraping, mechanize

A page with data I need has changed its structure to a new paginated format. I'm working on updating my scraper for the page.

I can't understand how to collect the data from all of the different pages.

The page to be scraped is: http://eserver.goutsi.com:8080/DPW230.cgi

I know how to collect the data in the tables but I can't figure out how to handle the pagination.

This is my original script:

```
scrape_actor = Mechanize.new
page = scrape_actor.get("http://loads.goutsi.com:8080/wntv5/BKLoad")
rows = page.body.to_s.split("</tr>")
rows.each do |row|
  if row.include? "bgcolor='#f5f5f5'"
    columns = row.split("</td>")
    i = 0
    while i < columns.count
      columns[i] = columns[i].gsub(%r{</?[^>]+?>},'').gsub(/[\n\t\r ]+/,'').gsub("&nbsp;",'')
      i+=1
    end
    username = "UTSI"
    origin = columns[0].gsub("&nbsp;","")
    pickup = Chronic.parse(columns[1]+"/"+Time.now.strftime("%Y"))
    dest = columns[3]
    comments = "miles: #{columns[4]}, phone: #{columns[9]}, other: #{columns[11]}"
    equipment = columns[6]
    ltl = false
    ltl = true if columns[7] == "LTL"
    Scrape.post_load(username,origin,dest,pickup,'',ltl,equipment,comments,'','','')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click one of the page links javascript on the page triggers a post request *to the same path* with the new page number.

This can be found in their js file at http://eserver.goutsi.com:8080/js/LoadBoard.js

```
function gotoPage(pageNumber) 
{
    document.getElementById("PageNbr").value= pageNumber;     // Set new page number
    document.getElementById("PageDir").value="R";             // Refresh
    document.getElementById("theForm").submit();
}
```

That code submits this form:

```
<form action="/DPW230.cgi" method="post" id="theForm">...
```

Which has the field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="PageDir" name="PageDir" value=" "><input type="hidden" id="PageNbr" name="PageNbr" value="1">
```

This `value` for which is updated in that same javascript.

**This means you need to make post requests to this URL with consecutive page numbers are params - then parse each page in turn aggregating the results.**